# python 2 strange list comprehension behaviour

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was looking around list comprehension and saw smth strange.
Code:

```
a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'c']
print [(len(list(g)), k) if len(list(g)) > 1 else k for k, g in groupby(a)]
```

Result:

`[(0, 'a'), 'b', (0, 'd'), (0, 'c')]`

But I wanted to see:

`[(3, 'a'), 'b', (2, 'd'), (3, 'c')]`

What's the cause of such behaviour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you call `list()` on an `itertools._grouper` object, you exhaust the object. Since you're doing this twice, the second instance results in a length of 0.

First:

```
if len(list(g))
```

now it's exhausted. Then:

```
(len(list(g)), k))
```

It will have a length of 0.

You can nest a generator/comprehension in your `list` comprehension to exhaust the object and save the relevant data before processing it:

```
>>> [(y,x) if y>1 else x for x,y in ((k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(a))]
[(3, 'a'), 'b', (2, 'd'), (3, 'c')]
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure the elements of `g` are consumed only once:

```
>>> print [(len(list(g)), k) if len(list(g)) > 1 else k for k, g in ((k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(a))]
[(3, 'a'), 'b', (2, 'd'), (3, 'c')]
```

This code will also iterate over `k, g in groupby(a)` but it'll turn `g` into a list object. The rest of the code can then access `g` as many times as needed (to check the length) without consuming the results.

Before making this change, `g` was a `itertools._grouper` object which means that you can iterate over `g` only once. After that it'll be empty and you won't be able to iterate over it again. That's why you're seeing length 0 appear in your results.